# hide/remove fragment added with tabsadapter in fragmenttabspager

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Im trying to remove or at least hide fragments and tabs created like in the FragmentTabsPager example from support4 package from Google. I can only use one activity as Im using webviews and want to use the same webpages.. Unfortunately the Tabsadapter class only contains a AddTab method and not a removetab. This class "relies on a trick" and I don't understand much of it..

this is how I create my tabs/fragments:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("workout").setIndicator("Workouts"),
            WorkoutFragment.class, null);
```

I have tried mTabsAdapter.destroyItem, without any luck. I have also tried to remove through fragmentTransaction, but without any luck:

`fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.hide(mTabsAdapter.getItem(1));
        fragTransaction.commit();`

I have found ways to remove just the tab, but the fragments stays around, causing 3 fragments on 2 tabs..
The rest of my code is basically the same as Fragmenttabspager example..

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you remove a tab?